# Пытаюсь подключиться к ftp через php, и выдает ошибку

Tags: php, ftp

Вот сам код подключения.

```
 <?php
 $host = "ftp://195.22.XXX.XXX";
 $connect = ftp_connect($host);
 if(!$connect)
  {
    echo("Ошибка соединения");
    exit;
  }
  else
  {
    echo("Соединение установлено");  
  }

?>
```

И выдает эту ошибку

```
Warning: ftp_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/u179140/landmarkstdru/educt/check_server.php on line 3
Ошибка соединения
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый аргумент в **ftp_connect** (переменная $host) не должен содержать префикса ftp:// в начале.

Comment: Вот изменил, теперь когда пытаюсь перейти то тупо бесконечная загрузка http://educt.landmarkstd.ru/check_server.php

Comment: Точно ли у Вас запущен FTP на 21 порту и разрешен доступ с этой машины (может ненастроен firewall и дропает пакеты)?

Comment: Диапазон портов от 1 до 50100, доступ к бд только с учеткой, сервер работает, через jav'y и filezilla все работает.

Comment: У вас нет коннекта к FTP серверу с данного хоста, поэтому ftp_connect отваливается по timeout

Comment: смысле  ? У меня прекрасно выходит подключаться через filezilla, через код на джаве с использование библиотеки от apach, а вот с php такие траблы.